# How to get name of currently loaded fxml file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, borderpane

I have `BorderPane`, which is divided to 3 `AnchorPane`s that are changing time to time. Is it possible to get full `.fxml` file name like 'MainScreen.fxml'? I can get `AnchorPane` with `System.out.println(getRootLayout().getCenter());`, but I can't figure out how to get it's name.

It's just I need to call from main class for method that is located in one of my controllers. But I want to call it only if certain fxml file for that controller is currently in use.

In short: if MainScreen.fxml is in use I will call it's MainScreenController's method, if not, then I won't.

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that; you would just need to store it from wherever you first loaded it. But why do you need this? It seems like there's a better way to do whatever it is you need this for.

Comment: A good solution for this could be to move the code initializing the CustomControl into a new class like UserControl and store the FXML-file in a protected variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question I assume that each AnchorPane is loaded from a different FXML file and that you keep a reference to their controllers in your application.

A simple solution would be to put the file information into the controller.

You can either do this manually...

```
URL location = getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml");
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(location);
// ... more fxmlLoader configuration ...
fxmlLoader.load();

// assuming your own Controller class has a setLocation method
Controller c = (Controller) fxmlLoader.getController();
c.setLocation(location);
```

... or rely on the FXMLLoader.

```
// your own Controller class
public class Controller
{
    // the URL will be automatically injected by the FXMLLoader
    // careful: the name of the field must be 'location'
    @FXML
    private URL location;

    // ...
}
```

Then you can simply add a `getLocation()` method to your controller to check from which file it was loaded.

*However, there is probably a better solution for your underlying problem that does not require checking for a specific file name.*